# Store extra data like refresh_token when signing up via access_token

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I am trying to signup using access token for google. My frontend is next.js with next-auth.js fetching the access_token, refresh_token, etc. I am using python social auth with Django to persist the user information. I use the access_token provided by next-auth to signup the user in Django. How do I make sure that the other response fields like refresh_token, and expires are saved in the Django DB? I can pass the required fields from next-auth to an API in Django but not sure what the expected format is.

https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use_cases.html#signup-by-oauth-access-token

```
@psa('social:complete')
def register_by_access_token(request, backend):
    # This view expects an access_token GET parameter, if it's needed,
    # request.backend and request.strategy will be loaded with the current
    # backend and strategy.
    token = request.GET.get('access_token')
    user = request.backend.do_auth(token)
    if user:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(get_tokens_for_user(user)))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking. Do you mean you need something like `RefreshToken.objects.create(refresh_token=refresh_token, ...)` ? This would save the token as a new row in the `RefreshToken` table. Again, I do not understand what you need exactly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Basically, I am trying to store the refresh token and other extra data from Google via next auth into the django database.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a table to store these tokens (not sure if you have one already), lets take this model as an example:

```py
class StoredToken(models.Model):
    refresh_token = models.CharField()
    access_token = models.CharField()

    # Maybe you need the related user too?
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

After you created your table, all you need is to save your data when you have it, from your example:

```py
def get_tokens_for_user(user):
    refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
    update_last_login(None, user)

    StoredToken.objects.create(refresh_token=refresh, access_token=refresh.access_token, user=user)

    return {
        'refresh': str(refresh),
        'access': str(refresh.access_token),
    }
```

You obviously need to do migrations to generate your table, but I assume you have the knowledge to do that. Otherwise refer to the [django documentation to create models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/)

Comment: This is not what I want. I am talking from the perspective of django python social auth sorting the extra data like refresh tokens etc

Answer (score 0):

I was able to store the refresh token along with other EXTRA_DATA in python social auth by adding `response` kwarg. This `response` kwarg is nothing but the dictionary containing the extra data.

For example: With Google, `response` is the return value of https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code

```
@psa
def register_by_access_token(request, backend):
    # If it's needed, request.backend and request.strategy will be loaded with the current
    # backend and strategy.
    response = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    user = request.backend.do_auth(response['access_token'], response=response)
    if user:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(get_tokens_for_user(user)))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
```